# Slice an Image into "Tiles" Using Numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have an image that I want to tile into smaller chunks for some deep learning purposes. I want to use numpy arrays to better understand using np.

Currently my image is loaded into a numpy array and its shape is:
(448, 528, 3)

I want to have a list of smaller, 8x8 chunks, I believe the representation would be (n, 8, 8, 3).

Currently when I take the following action:

```
smaller_image.reshape(3696, 8, 8, 3)
```

the image gets distorted.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So, you want to split the array of shape `502, 588, 3`, into n chunks each os shape `(8, 8, 3)`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: But, your input shape can't be evenly split into n chunks....

Comment: Is there a way to discard the overflow, or is the only way to preprocess?

Answer (score 10):

**[Update: New function generating a tile]**

```
import numpy as np

def get_tile_images(image, width=8, height=8):
    _nrows, _ncols, depth = image.shape
    _size = image.size
    _strides = image.strides

    nrows, _m = divmod(_nrows, height)
    ncols, _n = divmod(_ncols, width)
    if _m != 0 or _n != 0:
        return None

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        np.ravel(image),
        shape=(nrows, ncols, height, width, depth),
        strides=(height * _strides[0], width * _strides[1], *_strides),
        writeable=False
    )
```

Assume that we have `a_image` of shape `(448, 528, 3)`. To get a `28x33` tiles (each small image has size `16x16`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread(a_image)
tiles = get_tile_images(image, 16, 16)

_nrows = int(image.shape[0] / 16)
_ncols = int(image.shape[1] / 16)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=_nrows, ncols=_ncols)

for i in range(_nrows):
    for j in range(_ncols):
        ax[i, j].imshow(tiles[i, j]); ax[i, j].set_axis_off();
```